# Change value during validation in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model and am doing some validation when the setter is called. Instead of returning an error, I want to overwrite the value. How do I do this?

```
myObj = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  x: function() { },
  y: function() { },

      // Validation
      validate: function(atr) {

            // Checking for number
            var numberRegex = /^\d+$/;

            if(!numberRegex.test(atr.x)) // not number
                  atr.x = 'NA'; // Trying to set x to "NA"
      }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The atr you recieve inside your validate function is a copy of your model attributes .Therefore changing it will not change attributes in your model . To set attributes inside validate call `this.set('x','NA',{silent:true});`.